# Showing there is no covering map $\mathbb{R}P^2\to T^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I'm being asked to show there is no covering map $\R P^2\to T^2$ (the torus) by showing that every map $\R P^2\to T^2$ is null-homotopic, by lifting to the universal cover.

I know the universal cover of $T^2$ is $\R^2$ (call the map $p$), hence given any $f:(\R P^2,y_0)\to(T^2,x_0)$, it lifts to a unique $\tilde f:(\R P^2,y_0)\to(\R^2,\tilde x_0)$ for some $\tilde x_0\in p^{-1}(x_0)$.

I don't really see what is special about $\R P^2$ and $T^2$ in particular that will make any lift of this type null-homotopic, and I'm pretty stuck. I wish I could say I've tried more but I just don't know... does anybody have any hints/insight? I'd prefer a nudge in the right direction rather than just being given the answer.

Comment: First, how do you know the map $f$ lifts? (It does, but you didn't say why.) The lift $\tilde f$ is nullhomotopic since $\mathbb R^2$ is contractible (this is a standard exercise). If $H$ is the nulhomotopy for $\tilde f$, then $p \circ H$ is a homotopy from $f$ to a constant map.

Comment: @manthanomen I'm fairly certain the lift exists because the only homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\to \mathbb{Z}^2$ is the trivial map, hence $f_*\pi_1(\R P^2,y_0)=\{0\}=p_*\pi_1(\R^2,\tilde x_0)$. I really don't have as nice of intuition as I'd like for all this stuff.

Comment: @manthanomen OH wow okay I see why that works now. It made sense that $\tilde f$ was null-homotopic because $\R^2$ is contractible, but it seemed like that argument would work for any map between any spaces, because any (nice enough) space has a universal cover, so I was wondering what's special about $\R P^2$ and $T^2$ in this case. However, typing that out made me see it only works here because the only valid homomorphism between the two fundamental groups is the trivial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p: \mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ is a covering map then $p_*: \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, x) \to \pi_1(\mathbb{T}^2,p(x))$ which is the induced homomorphism, is injective. In view of this and the fact that the corresponding fundamental groups are $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ then $p_*$ is the trivial map and so therefore $p$ is null-homotopic. Since $p$ supposedly is a covering for the $2$-torus then this implies $\textrm{id}_{\mathbb{T}^2}$ is homotopic to a constant map i.e $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^2)$ is trivial which is a contradiction.